# How do I use multiple subsets in a data set?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set, "nz_bird," found in tidy tuesday (https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/tree/master/data/2019/2019-11-19). I am trying to determine the top 5 most voted bird breeds. My objective to demonstrate that is for each vote_rank, find the bird_breed with the highest number of votes. What would be the most effective means of subsetting the data without using `filter()` a lot.

I was thinking of trying multiple `group_by()` subsets but it doesn't seem to do anything.

[image: Attempting group_by() subsetting]

Answer (score 1):

```r
nz_bird%>%
  group_by(vote_rank, bird_breed)%>%
  summarize(Counts = n())%>%
  group_by(vote_rank)%>%
  filter(!is.na(bird_breed))%>%
  filter(Counts == max(Counts))
```

A tibble: 5 x 3

Groups:   vote_rank [5]

vote_rank bird_breed          Counts

1 vote_1    Yellow-eyed penguin   5757

2 vote_2    Kākāpō                2084

3 vote_3    Kākāpō                2056

4 vote_4    Kākāpō                1957

5 vote_5    Yellow-eyed penguin   1703

Comment: Is it ok that species were repeated in each rank? I got this same result in an earlier attempt.

Comment: Depends on the question you want answered, it is possible based on my understanding of the voting system.